# Sum all integers within a range [p,q] where p and q can be entered in any order

Tags: c, pointers, range

Just started learning C, and it would be great if you could help me with the following:

I just wrote a program that calculates the sum of all the integers within a range `[p, q]`. Both `p` and `q` are entered in any order the user wants. So far, the program works fine when `p < q`, but doesn't when `p > q`. To reorder the values of both `p` and `q` I am using function `reorder_range()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, I am not sure if the way I have organised the code is the proper one: a `main()` function that calls all the subprograms to run, rather than having everything within `main()`.

I am looking forward to reading any suggestions to improve this piece of code!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {
    int sum, range, i, p, q, aux;

    printf("Enter two integers:");
    range = scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);

    check_if_valid_value(range);  
    reorder_range(p, q, aux);
    dothesum(p, q, i, sum);
}

check_if_valid_value(range) {
    if (range != 2) {
        printf("You have not entered two integers.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}          

int reorder_range(int p, int q, int aux) {
    if (p > q) {
        aux = p;
        p = q;
        q = aux;
    }
}

int dothesum(int p, int q, int i, int sum) {  
    for (i = p; i <= q; ++i) {
        sum = sum + i;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to loop to get the sum. It's just an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) whose sum is n(p + q)/2

Comment: @phuclv You are right. I focused on the param-by-value issue and omitted analysing the core function. I'll add that info in my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much to everybody for the help. Upvoted @babon's answer as it fit best with the code I had! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one problem we are looking at here. For example, there are variables (`p` and `q`) which should be passed by reference (as mentioned in other answers), there are variables (`aux`, `i`, `sum`) which are not required to be passed, the return type of the functions (`check_if_valid_value(range)`) are not correct and some local variables (`sum`) were not initialized before being used.

Here is the program that does the job for two positive numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void check_if_valid_value(int range)
{
        if (range != 2) 
        {
                printf("You have not entered two integers.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
}          

void reorder_range(int *p, int *q)
{
        int aux;

        if (*p > *q)
        {
                aux = *p;
                *p = *q;
                *q = aux;
        }
}

void dothesum(int p,int q)
{  
        int i, sum;
        sum = 0;

        for (i = p; i <= q; ++i)
        {
                sum=sum+i;
                printf("%d\n", sum);
        }

}

int main(void)
{

        int range, p, q;

        printf("Enter two integers:");
        range=scanf("%d%d",&p,&q);

        check_if_valid_value(range);
        reorder_range(&p, &q);
        dothesum(p,q);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @babon! This one worked perfectly with my code. Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

In many programming problems, especially those involving mathematics like this one, the best solution requires a mathematical analysis as well. In this case, as correctly noticed by @phuclv, you are calculating the sum of an [arithmetic progression](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). So the actual solution requires just an immediate formula application.

The  reason why your solution doesn't work, anyway, is a conceptual mistake. I'll explain it so that it comprehension will help you in the future

---

In C function parameters are passed **by value**. It means that the value of the parameter is stored within **a copy** of it, and then used  in the function.

As a consequence, any change performed on a parameter will "live" until the function returns, when the parameters copies will be lost. **So the original parameters will be unchanged.**

Your function

```
int reorder_range(int p, int q, int aux)
{
    if (p>q)
    {
       aux=p;
        p=q;
        q=aux;
    }
}
```

has exactly this issue. The values will be swapped inside the function, but nothing will live outside it.

---

### The solution

In order to actually affect from a function external variables you have to use **pointers**: passing addresses will make possible changing their *contents*.

```
int reorder_range(int *p, int *q)
{
    if (p>q)
    {
        int aux = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = aux;
    }
}
```

From your `main ()`, just call the function passing the addresses of the variables containing the limits of your range:

```
reorder_range( &p, &q);
```

Answer (score 0):

In reorder_range function, changed p,q values don't affect p,q values in main method.

When you passed an argument in a method with values, it doesn't change the value in the first place.

As a solution, you can pass the reference to your p, q variables. 
In the main method before calling reorder_range,

```
int *pp = &p;
int *pq = &q;
```

then change your reorder_range function to take arguments as references.
then it will work.
for more information about pointer use following link.

[TutorialsPoint c - pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm)

Or you can create global variables for p and q then change them in your reorder_range function

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in function `reorder_range`: you are changing the values within the function but, when you return to the main, these values return to their original value. What you have to do is pass the memory address to change them inside the function.

A recommendation I give you is:

- the functions you have do not return anything, so you should place void instead of int
- the prototypes of the functions must be declared before the main
- the `check_if_valid_value` parameter is not declared

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in your code is in the `reorder_range` function: you only swap the values inside this function, without any side effect on the variables in the calling function. Arguments are passed by value in C, so changing the arguments inside a function does nt change the variables in the calling function. Passing pointers to the variables to reorder is a way to fix this problem.

There are other problems:

- omitting the return type when defining a function is an obsolete syntax. `main` should be defined as `int main()` or `int main(void)`, `reorder_range` should have a return type of `void`.
- `do_the_sum()` should only take the range boundaries, not the index and sum variables. You should define these as local variables.
- you should define or at least declare the functions before calling them.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void check_if_valid_value(int res) {
    if (res != 2) {
        printf("You have not entered two integers.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}          

int reorder_range(int *p, int *q) {
    if (*p > *q) {
        int aux = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = aux;
    }
}

int dothesum(int p, int q) { 
    int i, sum = 0; 
    for (i = p; i <= q; ++i) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int res, p, q;

    printf("Enter two integers:");
    res = scanf("%d%d", &p, &q);
    check_if_valid_value(res);  
    reorder_range(&p, &q);
    printf("%d\n", dothesum(p, q));
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that you do not really need more than a single function for your problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int p, q, i, sum;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &p, &q) != 2) {
        printf("You have not entered two integers.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (p > q) {
        int aux = p;
        p = q;
        q = aux;
    }
    sum = 0;
    for (i = p; i <= q; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally, the `for` loop can be omitted and the result computed directly this way:

```
printf("%d\n", (p + q) * (p - q + 1));
```

Using this simple expression, even reordering the range is no longer necessary:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int p, q;

    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &p, &q) != 2) {
        printf("You have not entered two integers.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", (p + q) * (abs(p - q) + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Purists will contend that `p + q`, `p - q`, `abs(p - q)` and further computations may have undefined behavior due to arithmetic overflow. That's correct indeed, and a good subject of interest for the OP. For example `p = q = MAX_INT` would produce an incorrect result with the direct expression, where the `for` loop would compute `sum = MAX_INT` correctly.